# Global linked list pointing to NULL when passed through a function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am facing this issue, in which if I am passing a linked list (which I defined as global) through a function (to insert a node), I am always getting a NULL value once the pointer returned to main function. 
However, if I am adding the node to the global defined, it is working fine which is expected too. Can someone please help me why this piece of code didn't work and *list always points to NULL

```
    struct node{
        int val;
        struct node *next;
    };

    typedef struct node node;
    static node *list=NULL;

boolean add_node(node *list, int n, int val)
{

    node *temp=NULL;
    temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->val = val;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if((list==NULL) && (n!=0))
    {
        printf("link list is NULL and addition at non zero index !");
        return (FALSE);
    }

    if(list==NULL)
    {
       printf("list is NULL ");
       list= temp;
    }
    else if(n==0)
    {
       temp-> next = list;
       list=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp2;
        temp2 = list;
        int count =0;
        while(count++ != (n-1))
        {
          temp2 = temp2->next;
          if(temp2==NULL)
          {
            printf("nth index %d is more then the length of link list %d ",n,count);
            return (FALSE);
          }
        }

        node *temp3;
        temp3 = temp2->next;
        temp2-> next = temp;
        temp->next = temp3;
    }

    printf("List after node insertion \n");
    print_link_list(list);
    return (TRUE);
}

main()
{
     c= getchar();
     switch(c)
        {
            case 'I':
            {
                printf("Insert a index and value  \n");
                int index,value;
                scanf_s("%d",&index);
                scanf_s("%d",&value);
                if(add_node(list,index,value)==FALSE)
                {
                    printf("Couldn't add the node \n");
                }

                if(list==NULL)
                {
                    printf("\n After Insert op.,list is NULL, add %x",list);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("After Inset op., list is not Null, add %x",list);
                }
            }
            break;
            case 'D':

....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The global variable `list` is never modified, only the parameter `list`.

You probably want that parameter to be a pointer to a pointer, and assign *through*, instead of *to*, the parameter.

Comment: Sorry, could you be a little bit more specific. 
If we modify this list in main function, it will work fine. But why not when I am passing this global pointer to some function. In this case too, i am still passing the memory location of the global pointer node *list.

Comment: No, you are passing the _value_ of the global variable. That is, the parameter list is a _copy_ of the global variable, and assigning to it changes the value of the copy, leaving the global `list` untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the function definition to use a pointer to a pointer:

```
boolean add_node(node **list, int n, int val)
```

You need to do this because your global variable `list` needs to be updated. The global is a pointer: an address. In your `add_node` function when you say `list = temp` you are only modifying the local pointer (also named list). When you leave the function the global list remains unchanged. However, if you pass a pointer *to* that global pointer (the pointer to a pointer) you are then able to modify the *address stored in the original pointer*.

An example:

```
int *pGlobal = NULL;

void someThing(int *pInt)
{
    int LocalInt = 3;
    pInt = &LocalInt; // I can change where this pointer is pointing - it's just a copy
    // pGlobal remains unchanged
}

void someThingElse(int **ppInt)
{
    // I am now modifying the ADDRESS of a pointer that we have the address of
    *ppInt = malloc(sizeof(int));
    // pGlobal has been changed to point at my allocated memory
}

void main()
{
    // This passes a COPY of the address held in pGlobal
    someThing(pGlobal);

    // Here we are now passing a pointer (address) TO another pointer.
    // The pointer pGlobal does occupy some real space in memory. We are passing a
    // COPY of the value of its location so we can modify it.
    someThingElse(&pGlobal);
}
```

Also, for good practice, don't name a global the same as a local variable (list) or parameter - it'll compile but can easily cause problems/confusion/bugs!

Comment: Thanks. Still wondering, how would passing double pointer help. 
With this code, am I not passing the memory address of global list pointer. 
  static node *list=NULL;-> let's say 0xaabb is the address which is pointing to NULL..

In main function,when I am calling this function
(add_node(list,index,value)==FALSE) -> 1st argument would be 0xaabb which would point to NULL. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. You are passing the address the pointer is holding, therefore modifications don't change the global pointer's value.